# PagedListPager does not contain definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@model IPagedList<eSchoolSemi.Web.Areas.NastavnikModul.ViewModels.OdrzaniCasIndexVM>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Areas/NastavnikModul/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Casovi</h1>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Class Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Subject</td>
                <td>@item.ClassName</td>
                <td>@item.Date</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/TeacherModule/HeldClasses/Edit?HeldClassID=@item.HeldClassID&ClassID=@item.ClassID&ClassName=@item.ClassName&Subject=@item.Subject">Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/TeacherModule/HeldClasses/Delete?HeldClassID=@item.HeldClassID&ClassID=@item.ClassID">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem here is, when I add

```
@Html.PagedListPager
```

It gives an error. Even though the model type is IPagedList. I have looked for answers on here and most of them are changing IEnumerable to IPagedList, but in my case it's been IPagedList the entire time.

In my controller I have

```
return View(VM.ToPagedList(page?? 1, 5));
```

So it's definitely returning a paged list... I have no idea what I am doing wrong here.

EDIT: For more info I am adding in the Index function from the controller

```
public IActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            UserData _User = HttpContext.GetLoggedUser();
            var Teacher = _db.Teacher.First(x => x.UserID == _User.LoggedUserID);

            var query = from O in _db.HeldClass
                        join OD in _db.Class on O.ClassID equals OD.ClassID
                        join NP in _db.Sylabus on OD.SylabusID equals NP.SylabusID
                        join NPP in _db.SylabusSubjects on NP.SylabusSubjectID equals NPP.SylabusSubjectID
                        join P in _db.Subject on NPP.SubjectID equals P.SubjectID
                        join A in _db.Employment on NPP.SylabusSubjectID equals A.SylabusSubjectID
                        where A.TeacherID == Nastavnik.UserID
                        orderby O.Date descending
                        select new { P.Name, OD.Symbol, O.ClassID, O.HeldClassID, O.Date };

            List<HeldClassIndexVM> VM = query.Select(x => new HeldClassIndexVM
            {
                ClassID = x.ClassID,
                Date = x.Date,
                HeldClassID = x.HeldClassID,
                Subject = x.Name,
                Symbol = x.Symbol
            }).ToList();

            return View(VM.ToPagedList(page?? 1, 5));
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the model as just `@model IPagedList`  and not with the type as `IPagedList<eSchoolSemi.Web.Areas.NastavnikModul.ViewModels.OdrzaniCasIndexVM>`

Comment: Nothing changes even after I put in just @model IPagedList

Comment: Can you show the rest of the action from your controller, please.

Comment: And, assuming you're using the Troy Goode PagedList then you need fulfil the requirements of the pager's signature e.g. `@Html.PagedListPager(Model,
                    x => Url.Action("Index", new { page = x }),
                    PagedListRenderOptions.OnlyShowFivePagesAtATime,
                            "span9 pagination-right"
                    )`

Comment: Added the info. And I already tried that, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Sorry I deleted that comment as it cross-posted with you uploading the Controller code.

Comment: It's been a while since I used that control but have you tried converting the VM list to an IEnumerable before passing the model to the view? You should be able to add `.AsEnumerable()` after the `.ToList()` - the documentation seems to suggest the control wants an IEnumerable or IQueryable.

Comment: adding either of those gives a conversion error. Stating it can't convert from System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable to System.Collection.Generic.List. And System.Linq.Queryable for the other one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190515/discussion-between-chessbrain-and-melkisadek).